# Printing all rows from a Postgres database array

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, php-pgsql

I'm trying to do a simple query from my postgres database, then try to manipulate the data.

Script I made goes as following;

```
function connectLocalDB() {

    $dbconnection = pg_connect("host=192.168.97.120 port=1337 dbname=x user=x password=x") or die("Unable to connect to Postgres");


    // INPUT table from userDB
    $userINPUTresult = pg_query($dbconnection, "SELECT * FROM \"INPUT\"");
    if (pg_num_rows($userINPUTresult)>0) {

        $userINPUTArray = pg_fetch_array($userINPUTresult);
        print_r($userINPUTArray);

        echo "INPUT CHAIN RULES LOADED \n";

    } else {

        echo ("NO INPUT CHAIN RULES \n");
    }
```

Now everything goes fine, except the printing only prints out the first row of the Database result set, while I have 3 rows in my database. What am I missing here?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.pg-fetch-array.php

Comment: The docs (http://www.php.net/pg_query) show you how to iterate a resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_fetch_array()` returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row (record)
if you have more than 1 record in table you should use `while` loop

as:

```
if (pg_num_rows($userINPUTresult)>0) {

        while($userINPUTArray = pg_fetch_array($userINPUTresult))
        {
        print_r($userINPUTArray);

        echo "INPUT CHAIN RULES LOADED \n";
        }
    } else {

        echo ("NO INPUT CHAIN RULES \n");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you loads. I have to read the documentation on PHP.net more carefully next time.